# Prebuild Step with file copy fails on VSO but succeeds in Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have a very simple pre-build step that I want to execute with my CI build using Visual Studio online.  The syntax of the step is as follows:

```
copy ("$(ProjectDir)Config\web.azure.config" "$(ProjectDir)runtime.config")
```

Both the source and destination file exist, this step works fine on all developer machines yet when I run on VSO I get an error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1247): The command "copy ("C:\a\src\MyProject\Tests\MyProject.WebAPI.Tests\Config\web.azure.config" "C:\a\src\MyProject\Tests\MyProject.WebAPI.Tests\runtime.config")
" exited with code 1.

The project in question is a unit test project which I use to execute unit tests after my build has succeeded.
I've also tried removing the brackets from the copy command.

I tried a similar approach using xcopy

```
xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)Config\web.azure.config" "$(ProjectDir)runtime.config
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the logs. I noticed that when I used *$(SolutionDir)*, it actually pointed to **my local** path, i.e. *C:\Users\Konrad\Source\...* and not, as I expected, to the server's location of the files. And, obviously, your agent has no privileges to access **that** directory nor does it exist. Please confirm that it's the case and that you still haven't resolved the issue and I'll try to provide you with a remedy. I'm fighting VSO right now so I'm up in combat mode, hehe.